# Timeout in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

How does paging work in SSRS?
Does it fetch whole data at one go and then just displays certain records per page or on clicking 'Next Page' it makes a DB call and pulls data from database and shows on screen everytime.

In my SSRS report, it ia taking considerable time to fetch around 3000 to 3500 records and show it on screen. So I want to know if Pagination can solve this problem.

To resolve timeout issue, I have mentioned Timeout as 36000 (Seconds) in Dataset properties.Also in Site settings of report manager, I have selected 'Do not timeout Report' Option.

Answer (score 0):

According to this artical it depends on the SQL server version you have:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bc1c71/custom-paging-in-sql-server-2012/

In SQL server 2012:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 comes with two extended clauses of ORDER BY and they are OFFSET & FETCH. These two clauses are used with Order By clause and make our SQL Engines to read only the specified number of records given with Fetch after the Offset value.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I can use Offset Fetch clause in my Sp but how can I make sure that it gets triggered when I click on Next/Prevuous button everytime. I want that on clicking Next button , it should go to Db and fetch relavan Data so that my processing time gets equally divided in every attempt instead og long delay in the beginning.

Comment: To my understand it'll be done automatically. BTW: The Next button will be added by the SSRS, you don't have to add it manually.

Comment: If that is the case then it will not cause timeout since it has to fetch fixed records (say 20) on every Next Button click.Thanks for your reply.